# QGIS - Add a graphical model as default

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

Is it possible to add a graphical model as default for all projects?

Instead of going to Processing/Graphical Modeler.. select the model and "Save model in project" every time I start a new project I want to add it so its available from start.

Comment: You could create a project containing said model and e.g. some preset styles and save it as preset in the general tabs in the options.

Comment: Hmm, I can not follow your suggestion. Is you suggestion to add it do a new project and save that project as a "template" that I can reuse in the future? (which works)

Comment: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#general-settings - look at the project files settings

Answer (score 1):

The trick if you want your model to be shared across projects, is to *not* save it *to the project*. Saving models to your project is great if you want to share it and have the models shared with it. Otherwise, QGIS has [User profiles](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#working-with-user-profiles) that models are normally shared to. You will probably not have to worry about them too much if you are only using one profile.

1. make a model
2. save your model: [image: Save model (Ctrl-S)]
3. open a new project and see it magically appear! [image: the model in processing toolbox]